# Eloquent: hasNot with parameter

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have the following eloquent models:

**User** | id

**Post** | id

**Comment** | id | post_id | user_id

Using eloquent, how can I fetch all Posts which a specific User hasn't commented yet?

I tried so far:

In Model **Post**:

```
public function noCommentOf(User $user) {
    $this->hasNot('App\Comment')->commentOf($user);
}
```

In Model **Comment**:

```
public function commentOf($query, User $user) {
    return $query->where('user_id', '=', $user->id);
}
```

Comment: not that hard question, a bit complex but not difficult. What have you done till now to solve this problem?

Comment: Hi! I added some short code snippets how I tried it so far.

Comment: ok, I will have a look, will be back in some minutes

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The way I would do this is by querying the `Post` model with a `whereDoesnthave` relationship. In your controller:

```
public function getPostsWithoutCommenter(){
  $userId = 1; // Could be `$user`, `use($user)` and `$user->id`.
  $posts = \App\Post::whereDoesntHave("comments", function($subQuery) use($userId){
    $subQuery->where("user_id", "=", $userId);
  })->get();
}
```

This would assume that `comments` is defined on the `Post` model as:

```
public function comments(){
  return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

Basically, if the `comments` relationship with the check for that `$userId` returns a `Collection`, it would be ignored from the result set.

Comment: Thank you, very nice solution! :)

Answer (score 11):

Post model

```
public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class)
}
```

Then get posts

```
$posts = Post:: whereDoesntHave('comments', function ($query) use ($userId) {
    $query->where('user_id', $userId);
});
```

To get posts with no comments

```
$posts = Post::has('comments', '=', 0)->get();
```

Comment: how about posts with no comments?

Comment: @AndriyLozynskiy Updated my answer.

Answer (score -1):

I think:

```
$user->post()->leftJoin('comments', 'posts.id', '=', 'comments.post_id')->whereNull('comments.id');
```

Answer (score -3):

In order to fetch all posts that a specific user hasn't commented on using Laravel's Eloquent ORM, you can utilize the `whereDoesntHave()` method in combination with query constraints.

First, define the following relationships in your models:

```
class User extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}

class Post extends Model
{
    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
    }
}
```

Next, in your Post model, define a scope called `noCommentOf()` that accepts a User instance as a parameter:

```
public function scopeNoCommentOf($query, User $user)
{
    $query->whereDoesntHave('comments', function ($query) use ($user) {
        $query->where('user_id', $user->id);
    });
}
```

Now, you can use this scope to fetch all posts that the specific user hasn't commented on:

```
$user = User::find($userId);

$posts = Post::noCommentOf($user)->get();
```

Comment: Did you bother to look at the 6 year old accepted answer before posting?

Comment: @miken32 I imagine this was ChatGPT generated (based on other recent answers from this user)

Comment: why are you making every where that did with chatGPT

Comment: @DavidW yup, there weren’t other recent answers to go on when I left my comment. I was suspicious enough to check though…